# Escape ContainsTable Keywords

Tags: sql-server, escaping, containstable

How can I escape ContainsTable control keywords (such as NEAR or ISABOUT) so that Full Text Search will actually look for those words, and not treat them as control keywords?

Answer (score 1):

Just create your own StopWords in a StopList and put in your full-text index

Regards,

DavLeMag

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried delimiting the words: "..." or [...] ?